# in test bench of SRFF terminal showing error " ; is expected instead of identifier

Tags: terminal, vhdl, test-bench, flip-flop, ghdl

I found this error in this testbench for SR FF.
While I am compiling it using GHDL in terminal, it is showing the error

> ; is expected instead of ''

I am just a beginner, so that I can't find the error.
Can anyone please help me?

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity SR_tb is
end SR_tb;

architecture behavioral of SR_FF is
    component SR_FF is
        port  (S,R,CLOCK:in std_logic;
        Q,QBAR:out std_logic);  
    end component;
signal clock,s,r,q,qbar: std_logic;
constant clock_period : time := 10 ns;
begin
    port_map:SR_FF port map (clock=>CLOCK,s=>S,r=>R,q=>Q,qbar=>QBAR);

clock_process:process
 begin
      clock <='0';
      wait for clock_period/2;
      clock <= '1';
      wait for clock period/2;
end process;
stim_proc:process
begin 
       s<= '0';
        r<= '0';
        wait for 50 ns;   
        s<= '0';
        r<= '1';
        wait for 50 ns;
        s<= '1';
        r<= '0';
        wait for 50 ns;
        s<= '1';
        r<= '1';
        wait for 50 ns;
assert false report "reached end of test";
wait;
end process;

end behavioral;
```

Comment: This looks like VHDL (though I am not a vhdl expert). You should add the tag 'vhdl' to this post and you might get an answer.

Comment: I added the GHDL tag and improved some overall spelling and formatting.

Comment: What line do you get the error? That might give a hint.

Comment: Shouldn't `assert false report "reached end of test";` be `assert false report "reached end of test" severity note;`. I am not so familiar with this statement though.